# Store password in irreversible encrypted format in web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, web-config, configuration-files, password-encryption

I have an MVC application that needs to authenticate an active directory account. I want to store the account name and password in the web.config file.

What i'm looking for are suggestions for the best bullet proof way of storing this accounts password in an irreversible encrypted format in the web.config file.

However, an alternative way of approaching this requirement is welcome too as i'm doing this kind of thing for the first time, so i'm not sure how others have gone about securely storing a password in web.config file and then reading it from the application.

Comment: Encryption is not irreversible. Passwords need to be hashed (and preferably salted) as well. Then you hash the user's input using the same hashing algorithm and compare the results.

Comment: Thanks for the mention of hashing instead of encryption. In my scenario, there will be not be user input, it's only authenticating a know account against AD but the Admins can not provide the password in plain text for storage in the web.config. Do u think the admins can hash & salt the password, then give me the  hashed & salted password to store in config file as password.

Comment: Not sure I understand the scenario or why you would need to do this, but I see no reason why not. [This article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) is worth reading.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky(v=vs.140).aspx

That is encrypting/decrying though, what I think you are asking for is a one way hash. If you want to hash that is fairly easy, but that would require you to store the hash in the web.config. Then when a logon attempt happens you then hash the submitted password using your predefined algorithm and compare for a match.

How to do hashing:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704865/Salted-Password-Hashing-Doing-it-Right

Code for hashing in c# using a known salt. This was lifted from somewhere else long ago.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Helpers
{
public class SaltedHashPassword
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Hashed password to save.
    /// </summary>
    public string Hash { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Salt used to generate the hased password. Save with the password as well.
    /// </summary>
    public string Salt { get; private set; }

    public SaltedHashPassword(string password)
    {
        var saltBytes = new byte[32];
        using (var provider = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
        {
            provider.GetNonZeroBytes(saltBytes);
        }
        Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
        var passwordAndSaltBytes = Concat(password, saltBytes);
        Hash = ComputeHash(passwordAndSaltBytes);
    }

    public static bool Verify(string salt, string hash, string password)
    {
        var saltBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);
        var passwordAndSaltBytes = Concat(password, saltBytes);
        var hashAttempt = ComputeHash(passwordAndSaltBytes);
        return hash == hashAttempt;
    }

    static private string ComputeHash(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var sha512 = SHA512.Create())
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(sha512.ComputeHash(bytes));
        }
    }

    static private byte[] Concat(string password, byte[] saltBytes)
    {
        var passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        return passwordBytes.Concat(saltBytes).ToArray();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I actually might recommend using the code in the CodeProject article you linked instead of the code you shared. Seems to work better for my purposes, anyways.

Comment: Good to know, if the answer helped please mark as the selected. Thanks.